# How to solve this problem related to primes without iteration?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $\mathrm{gcd}(24,x) = 1$, $x <= 100$ and $24 + x = p. $  $p \in \mathbb{P}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of primes.

An obvious solution is found once we iterate through the values of $x$ and find if $24+x$ is prime on a case by case basis, for example - I can find all the primes between 24 and 124 by iteration/ Sieve of  Eratosthenes- however, I'm interested in a solution that doesn't use iteration. I showed it to a math professor - and he recommended the Peano Theorem? I'm unsure as to how I can use it!

I tried using the fact that $p^2 -1 = 0$ mod $24$ for $p >3$, however - that lead nowhere.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What was his Peano Theorem?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iy2Pi19KmkmKOi8y48U9YSSHhfKLhbV-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, I know that one (on ODE's) but I really wonder what your professor had in mind, and I thought there would be another one (on arithmetic).

Comment: Yes, I have no clue what he's talking about!

Answer (score 1):

Since the prime factors of $24$ are $2,3$ you can see that $x$ has the form $6k\pm 1$, and the largest number of that form less than $100$ is $97$. So you want to count primes in the range $24+1=25$ to $24+97=121$. The largest prime on the low end which is excluded is $23=p_9$, and the largest prime which in included is $113=p_{30}$. That gives $21$ primes as the answer.

Comment: This is more or less similar to the iterative process that I mentioned. Infact, correct me if I'm wrong but instead of applying the 6k+1 constraint we can simply count the number of primes between 24 and 124 to get the answer.

Comment: I understood 'iterative' to imply looking at every number $24+i$ in the range $25$ to $124$ (not just those of the form $6k\pm 1$) and deciding whether it was prime or not. Apologies if I misunderstood.

Comment: Ahh I see. I realise that the usage of the word "iterative" is confusing - I've edited it in the question. Do you have any alternative solutions perhaps?

Comment: The best I can do that is shorter is to give a maximum: Since the numbers of the form $6k\pm 1$ represent one-third of all integers, the $99$ numbers from $25$ to $124$ can feature at most $33$ numbers of that form. That still leaves you with deciding how many are or are not prime.